# wxpython + add toolbar to panel

Tags: wxpython, panel, toolbar

I want to add a toolbar to my panel. this is my code:

```
    self.toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self,-1)
    self.newtool= self.toolbar.AddTool(self, -1,'',  wx.Bitmap('tnew.png'))
    self.opentool= self.toolbar.AddTool(self,-1,'', wx.Bitmap('topen.png'))
    self.savetool= self.toolbar.AddTool(self,-1,'',  wx.Bitmap('tsave.png'))
    self.qtool= self.toolbar.AddTool(self,-1,'', wx.Bitmap('texit.png'))
    self.toolbar.Realize()
```

But it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: in method 'ToolBarBase_DoAddTool', expected argument 2 of type 'int'
```

In the documentation I found:

```
AddSimpleTool(self, id, bitmap, shortHelpString, longHelpString, isToggle)
```

I also tried this:

```
DoAddTool(self, id, label, bitmap, bmpDisabled, kind, shortHelp, longHelp, clientData)
```

But it gives the same error.

Any suggestion?
tx

Comment: try removing self as the first argument when calling AddTool

Comment: Thanks this works!